# how to show progress dialog onitemclick, android

Tags: android, progressdialog

Hi I have created an Activityname as ZBC. Where i have created Customized List view I am able to detect on click event using onItemClick() method of OnItemClickListener on list view. I want progress dialog to be displayed on click on ListView. I used the following code but I didnot get ProgressDialog

How to display progress dialog in onItemClick method

```
ProgressDialog.show(ABC.this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

But I didnot get ProgressDIalog

how to show progress dialog onitemclick, android

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my application:

ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, null, getText(R.string.loading), true, true);

Giving null and not empty string as title, and it is cancelable.

Where did you set the onItemClickListener, some contect may be helpful? Maybe you are call it on wrong place.